# List that inherits permission cannot be accessed

Tags: access-denied

I have SP 2010.
I just created user groups and added everyone there.
They can access the site but they cant access the custom list I created.
The list inherits permission from the page. Users are getting error:access denied
Please help!

Comment: Have you changed access to the Style Library library?  Or are there any customisations on the Master Page?  This can be a reason that a List can not be accessed.  Perhaps there are custom scripts that prevent the page from being loaded up?  I've added a css script to a Master Page before and it stopped users from being able to access the entire site.  (Their permissions had not been changed).